# Hiding a <dl> if there is no <img> content inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write this post to seek a solution for my issue. For example I have this html code

```
<dl class="rpg-dll">
 <dt><span>Character</span> :</dt>
 <dd class="rpg-l">
  <span><span><img src="IMAGE.PNG" /></span></span>
</dd>
</dl>
```

And 3 copies but without <'img>

```
<dl class="rpg-dll">
 <dt><span>Character</span> :</dt>
 <dd class="rpg-l">
  <span><span>NO IMAGE</span></span>
</dd>
</dl>
```

How to hide the whole <'dl> if there is no <'img> inside of it? I mean, I randomly choose to show an only one and hide the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for jQuery solution can use

```js
$('.rpg-dll').not(':has(img)').hide()// or remove() to take it out completely
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="rpg-dll">
 <dt><span>Character</span> :</dt>
 <dd class="rpg-l">
  <span><span><img src="IMAGE.PNG" /></span>IMAGE HERE</span>
</dd>
</dl>



<dl class="rpg-dll">
 <dt><span>Character</span> :</dt>
 <dd class="rpg-l">
  <span><span>NO IMAGE</span></span>
</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, But my jQuery library running in 1.7.2 seems conflict with version 2.1.1 :(

Comment: I just chaanged jQuery source in my demo to 1.7.2 and works fine. Don't add another copy of jQuery.js to your page.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-jQuery solution, you can check using `element.querySelectorAll().length` if the element contains an Image:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("dl.rpg-dll")).forEach(el => {
  let hasImage = el.querySelectorAll("img").length > 0;
  if(!hasImage) el.style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<dl class="rpg-dll">
 <dt><span>Character</span> :</dt>
 <dd class="rpg-l">
  <span><span><img src="https://placehold.it/300" /></span></span>
</dd>
</dl>

<dl class="rpg-dll">
 <dt><span>Character</span> :</dt>
 <dd class="rpg-l">
  <span><span>NO IMAGE</span></span>
</dd>
</dl>

<dl class="rpg-dll">
 <dt><span>Character</span> :</dt>
 <dd class="rpg-l">
  <span><span>NO IMAGE</span></span>
</dd>
</dl>

<dl class="rpg-dll">
 <dt><span>Character</span> :</dt>
 <dd class="rpg-l">
  <span><span>NO IMAGE</span></span>
</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thank you Luca but when I did appy this script to my test site, it didn't work as expected. Here is my test site http://rotavn.forumotion.com/h16- sorry can't put it in html tag

Comment: that's because you put your code above the elements, move it to the bottom of the page, and it should work just fine! Or put the code inside of a function and attach an event listener for the load event to the window

Comment: Ah you right, I didn't think about :D Been thought that I could put it everywhere inside the page.

Thank you so much!